# Accessing integration point number in Abaqus 2022

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to access integration point numbers in ABAQUS 2022 through a VUMAT-subroutine.

I am aware that it has earlier been possible to do this through subroutine vumatXtrArg(...). However, given that, since version 2020 it is possible to access element number directly via jInfoArray I expect it should be possible also for integration points. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier than I'd like to admit. As far as I can tell, it is simply the variable denoted as *kspt* in the VUMAT manual.